# Vuex not working in boiler plate Nuxt app

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, nuxt.js

I am unable to get Vuex to work with Nuxt out of the box. I did try following this guide, but I get the following error

The error I am getting:

```
TypeError
Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

Steps to reproduce:

```
npx create-nuxt-app

\\Options selected

? Project name **VueNuxtApp**
? Project description **My epic Nuxt.js project**
? Use a custom server framework **none**
? Choose features to install (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to invert selection)
? Use a custom UI framework **none**
? Use a custom test framework **none**
? Choose rendering mode **Universal**
? Author name
? Choose a package manager **npm**

npm run dev
```

Replaced the `pages/index.vue` with following:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>The website says</h3>
    <p>{{ greeting }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: mapState([
    'greeting'
  ]),
}
</script>
```

Added `store/index.js` with:

```
export const state = () => ({
  greeting: 'Hello, World'
})
```

Comment: you have a error somewhere else. You code is working and your problem not reproducibel by the steps you described

Comment: Thanks for helping, Aldarund. Were you able to get it to work in this example? I have tried it a few times without luck.

Comment: Yes, I was. Create a codesandboc or GitHub repo with your problem.

Comment: Alright. It seems a restart was required in order to make this work. I am not sure if this is a thing which hot reload in nuxt does not support.

Comment: it should work even without hot reload

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. A restart was required in order to reflect the changes. I haven't seen a mention of this in the official guide though.